# Edge issue for handle candidate

Tags: javascript, jquery, video-streaming, webrtc

I try get done a video chat using webrtc and adapter.js on Chrome is working fine but on EI Edge is not, first is show to me this warning Timeout for addRemoteCandidate. Consider sending an end-of-candidates notification this is coming from adapter.js I don't know how can fix this issue can some one help me please.

```
/*===========================================
* handle offer 
============================================*/
async function handleOffer(offer) {
    await handleJoinSuccess();

    console.log('receiver offer: ', offer);
    try {
        let remoteSessionDescriptions = new RTCSessionDescription(offer);

        await pc.setRemoteDescription(remoteSessionDescriptions)
        console.log('remote is set');

        const answer = await pc.createAnswer();

        if (!state.iAmCaller) {
            await pc.setLocalDescription(answer)
        }

        await socketVideoEmit('answer', answer);
        console.log(TAG, 'socketEmit')
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('error', error)
    }
}


function handleAnswer(answer) {

    pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(answer));
    console.log('remote is set');
}
```

here is my function for handle it

```
function handleIceCandidate(candidate) {

    console.log(candidate);

    pc.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(candidate)).catch(error => {
        console.log('error adding icecandidate', error)
    });    

}
```

Here is the candidate socket

```
function onReceivedVideoMessage(data) {
    console.log(TAG + 'onReceivedVideoMessage(data)', data)
    if (data.toid == IM_USERID) {
        let videoChatSocketTag = data.type;
        switch (videoChatSocketTag) {
            case "offer":
                setState({ connectionState: ConnectionStates.receivedOfferState })
                handleOffer(data.data);
                break;
            case "answer":
                setState({ connectionState: ConnectionStates.receiveAnswerState })
                handleAnswer(data.data);
                break;
            case "candidate":
                setState({ connectionState: ConnectionStates.receivedIceCandidateState });
                console.log('receiver candidate');
                handleIceCandidate(data.data);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's very hard for us to help you if you don't share some code

Comment: Also note that IE and Edge are two completely different browsers. Can you please be specific when stating which one it's not working in (or is this applying to both?)

Comment: This issue is happening in Edge